# Retrieve elements from database using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate and trying to learn . I have a table with name "Customer" and two columns "customer_Name" and "Cars"

```
   customer_name          Cars        
      A                    Ford
      A                    Hyundai
      A                    Audi
      B                    Merc
      B                    Volvo
      C                    AstonMartin
      C                    Nissan
```

Using hibernate ,how can I get the Cars each customer has based on his name . 
i.e. "customer_name"  A has three "Cars" Ford,Hyundai and Audi.
I want to use Criteria to do this .
Can we do this without using hql queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Customer.class);

if(customer_name!=null)
{
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("customer_name", customer_name));
}

List<Customer> customers = (Customers)criteria.list();
```

You can read more from [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/).